# Could someone explain the meaning of this statement in Griffiths?

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm having some problem with the following statement:

> the volume current density is a function of source coordinates, not field coordinates

What is this statement supposed to mean?

Here $\mathbf A$ is the magnetic vector potential, $\mathbf J$ is the volume current density, and $\mathbf r$ is the position vector of any point where this vector potential is to be calculated. The full statement is below.

---

> Problem 5.27
>
> (a) $\nabla\cdot\mathbf A=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \int \nabla\cdot\left(\frac{\mathbf J}{{}}\right)d\tau'$.
> $\nabla\cdot\left(\frac{\mathbf J}{{}}\right)=\frac{1}{{}} \nabla\cdot \mathbf J + \mathbf J \cdot \nabla \frac{1}{{}}$. But the first term is zero, because $\mathbf J(\mathbf r')$ is a function of the *source* coordinates, not the *field* coordinates. And since $\mathbf{}=\mathbf r-\mathbf r'$, $ \nabla \frac{1}{{}}=- \nabla' \frac{1}{{}}$.

Comment: An excellent website to help you on your way might be http://www.physicspages.com/2013/04/07/magnetic-vector-potential-div-curl-and-laplacian/

Answer (score 2):

It means that $\nabla\cdot \vec{A}=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int \nabla\cdot\frac{\vec{J}}{s}dr'$, when written down explicitly, is 
$$\nabla\cdot \vec{A}(\vec{r})=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int \nabla\cdot\frac{\vec{J}(\vec{r}')}{s}dr',$$
where $\nabla=\nabla_r$.
That is, $r$ is the filed coordinates since it is in $\vec{A}(\vec{r})$ on the left hand side and $r'$ is the source coordinates since it is in $\vec{J}(\vec{r}')$ on the right hand side.